# How can I redirect all Subdomains to https

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, cpanel

Hello what should add to htaccess to redirect all subdomains to https for example webmail.example.com?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  RewriteOptions inherit
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
  RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]

</IfModule>

Header set content-Security-Policy: upgrade-insecure-requests
```

Comment: And your current rule is presumably not doing this? What happens exactly? Does `webmail.example.com` resolve to this place on the filesystem? What is `RewriteOptions inherit` doing? (What rules are you _inheriting_?)

Comment: I'm redirecting 6 more domains to my main domain. Right now when I go to webmail.example.com, it opens the HTTP form but I can manually go to HTTPS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
> RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
> ```

You already have a rule that redirects everything (any domain/subdomain) to HTTPS. So if this is not working then either:

1. This subdomain is *not* pointing to the same area of the filesystem (so this `.htaccess` file does not apply and the directives are ignored).
2. These directives are not doing anything, ie. mod_rewrite or `.htaccess` overrides are not enabled on your server.

Since you have a "front-controller" pattern in the `.htaccess` file (the *last* rule), I assume this is being used successfully to serve your website? If so then `.htaccess` and mod_rewrite would appear to be enabled and working.

That would seem to leave **#1**.
In which case is the `webmail` subdomain pointing to this area of the filesystem?

Is the `webmail` subdomain something that you've created or is this part of your hosting account? `webmail` is a common subdomain that cPanel uses (and you have tagged your question `cPanel`). In which case, this subdomain likely points to an entirely different area of the filesystem and is out of your control.

Comment: Yes, webmail is for Cpanel. So I can't force it to HTTPS?

Comment: @MjEbrahimzadeh If you are in a _shared_ server environment and your host does not provide additional support then unfortunately not. Some webhosts will redirect these subdomains to HTTPS for you, but otherwise, this is not something you can control yourself - short of deleting them altogether. cPanel creates a number of subdomains that you have no direct control over (and unfortunately some of these can get indexed if links are discovered).

Comment: Do `.htaccess` files overide each other? I got two Wordpress installations on my webspace and one is one a subdomain for staging purposes. Wordpress automatically created a `.htaccess` file. Then I had to write the https-override in this `.htaccess` as well. Does this `htaccess` file override the other? Thanks in advance

Comment: @Thunermay If the subdomain is pointing to a _subdirectory_ then in your case, most probably yes. However, it is a bit more complex than that. It depends on the Apache module. I suspect you are really asking about "mod_rewrite". Yes, by default, mod_rewrite directives completely override the parent (the parent directives do not execute at all) - but this behaviour can be changed. (In the question the OP has `RewriteOptions inherit` - this changes that behaviour - there are many options.) Most other modules override and _merge_ with the parent directives.

Comment: @Thunermay If you have a staging site then it would probably be better to have this is an entirely different area of the filesystem (not a subdirectory) in order to avoid potential conflicts.

Comment: @MrWhite Thank You very much!!! This expanded my knowledge about htaccess and mod_rewrite A LOT.

Comment: @MrWhite Yeah I know but this is temporary and probably only once to migrate the website to wordpress. But thanks for the tip!